# Spark aggregations where output columns are functions and rows are columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I want to compute a bunch of different agg functions on different columns in a dataframe.

I know I can do something like this, but the output is all one row.

```
df.agg(max("cola"), min("cola"), max("colb"), min("colb"))
```

Let's say I will be performing 100 different aggregations on 10 different columns.

I want the output dataframe to be like this -

```
      |Min|Max|AnotherAggFunction1|AnotherAggFunction2|...etc..
cola  | 1 | 10| ... 
colb  | 2 | NULL| ... 
colc  | 5 | 20| ... 
cold  | NULL | 42| ... 
...
```

Where my rows are each column I am performing aggregations on and my columns are the aggregation functions.  Some areas will be null if I don't calculated `colb` max for example.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Map column, say `Metrics`, where keys are column names and values a struct of aggregations (max, min, avg, ...). I am using [`map_from_entries`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#map_from_entries) function to create a map column (available from Spark 2.4+). And then, simply explode the map to get the structure you want.

Here is an example you can adapt for your requirement:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("A", 1, 2), ("B", 2, 4), ("C", 5, 6), ("D", 6, 8)], ['cola', 'colb', 'colc'])

agg = map_from_entries(array(
    *[
        struct(lit(c),
               struct(max(c).alias("Max"), min(c).alias("Min"))
               )
        for c in df.columns
    ])).alias("Metrics")

df.agg(agg).select(explode("Metrics").alias("col", "Metrics")) \
    .select("col", "Metrics.*") \
    .show()

#+----+---+---+
#|col |Max|Min|
#+----+---+---+
#|cola|D  |A  |
#|colb|6  |1  |
#|colc|8  |2  |
#+----+---+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution which allows you to set aggregations dynamically from a predefined list. The solution uses [map_from_arrays](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#map_from_arrays) among others therefore is compatible with Spark >= 2.4.0:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, expr, array, map_from_arrays

df = spark.createDataFrame([
  [1, 2.3, 5000],
  [2, 5.3, 4000],
  [3, 2.1, 3000],
  [4, 1.5, 4500]
], ["cola", "colb", "colc"])

aggs = ["min", "max", "avg", "sum"]
aggs_select_expr = [f"value[{idx}] as {agg}" for idx, agg in enumerate(aggs)]

agg_keys = []
agg_values = []

# generate map here where key is col name and value an array of aggregations
for c in df.columns:
  agg_keys.append(lit(c)) # the key i.e cola
  agg_values.append(array(*[expr(f"{a}({c})") for a in aggs])) # the value i.e [expr("min(a)"), expr("max(a)"), expr("avg(a)"), expr("sum(a)")]

df.agg(
  map_from_arrays(
    array(agg_keys), 
    array(agg_values)
  ).alias("aggs")
) \
.select(explode("aggs")) \
.selectExpr("key as col", *aggs_select_expr) \
.show(10, False)

# +----+------+------+------+-------+
# |col |min   |max   |avg   |sum    |
# +----+------+------+------+-------+
# |cola|1.0   |4.0   |2.5   |10.0   |
# |colb|1.5   |5.3   |2.8   |11.2   |
# |colc|3000.0|5000.0|4125.0|16500.0|
# +----+------+------+------+-------+
```

**Description:** with expression `array(*[expr(f"{a}({c})") for a in aggs])` we create an array that contains all the aggregations of the current column. Each item of the generated array is being evaluated with the statement `expr(f"{a}({c})"` this will produce i.e `expr("min(a)")`.

The array will consist the values of `agg_values` which together with `agg_keys` will compose our final map through the expression `map_from_arrays(array(agg_keys), array(agg_values))`. This is how the structure of map looks like:

```
map(
    cola -> [min(cola), max(cola), avg(cola), sum(cola)]
    colb -> [min(colb), max(colb), avg(colb), sum(colb)]
    colc -> [min(cola), max(colc), avg(cola), sum(colc)]
)
```

In order to extract the information that we need we must explode the previous map with `explode("aggs")` this will create two columns `key` and `value` which we use in our select statement.

`aggs_select_expr` will contain values in the form of `["value[0] as min", "value[1] as max", "value[2] as avg", "value[3] as sum"]` which will be the input of the `selectExpr` statememnt.

**UPDATE:**

I realized that there is a more performant way by omitting the aggregation aka implicit `groupBy` through `agg`. We can achieve the same through the `create_map` built-in function:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import create_map, expr, array
from itertools import chain

df = spark.createDataFrame([
  [1, 2.3, 5000],
  [2, 5.3, 4000],
  [3, 2.1, 3000],
  [4, 1.5, 4500]
], ["cola", "colb", "colc"])

aggs = ["min", "max", "avg", "sum"]
aggs_select_expr = [f"value[{idx}] as {agg}" for idx, agg in enumerate(aggs)]

df.select(explode(
                  create_map(*list(
                        chain(*[(lit(c), array(*[expr(f"{a}({c})") for a in aggs])) 
                          for c in df.columns
                     ])))
                   )
         ) \
        .selectExpr("key as col", *aggs_select_expr)
```

**Note**: Additionally to less code, the main advantage of the 2nd approach is the fact that it contains only narrow transformation and not wide i.e `groupBy`. That we will improve the performance since it avoids shuffling.